# how to set style of menu::item::selected in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets

I want to set color of the border of a menu item when user set focus on it. First - item::selected, is this right property? And if yes, how to set this? Do i use Designer or do it manually in C++ code?

```
Customizing QMenu Individual items of a QMenu are styled using the 'item' subcontrol as follows:  

         QMenu {
             background-color: #ABABAB; /* sets background of the menu */
             border: 1px solid black;  }

         QMenu::item {
             /* sets background of menu item. set this to something non-transparent
                 if you want menu color and menu item color to be different */
             background-color: transparent;  }

         QMenu::item:selected { /* when user selects item using mouse or keyboard */
             background-color: #654321;  }
```

OK, but where to put this in Qt 5.0? Do I use this in **Designer** in **stylesheet** property? I guess NO. In my .cpp files? I can do `setStyleSheet` on my menu but how to specify ::item::selected?

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QWidget>
#include <QtWidgets/QMessageBox>
cf16tradingclient_1::cf16tradingclient_1(){
    widget.setupUi(this);
    widget.menuMarket->setStyleSheet(?????????) // I want item::selected
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply do:

```
widget.menuMarket->setStyleSheet("QMenu::item:selected{border:1px solid red;}");
```

That's the right place to do it if you only want one specific menu to behave like that. (I don't see why setting that in Designer wouldn't work. Give it a try. But I'm not familiar with it myself.)

If you want all your menus to have the same style, do it at the `QApplication` level, in your `main` or some other piece of code that runs once at startup.

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);
// ...
app.setStyleSheet("QMenu::item:selected {border: 5px solid yellow;}");
// ...
```

And you can combine the two. The stylesheet you place on a specific widget (first example) will override the global stylesheet (much like CSS does).

<sub>This works the same in Qt4 and Qt5, though Qt5 might have more style options.</sub>